# Where can I download Ubuntu One for Android as an APK?

Tags: ubuntu-one, android, launchpad

The Android on my phone is modded, does not have Google Marketplace and I don't want to install it.

Where can I download an APK to install Ubuntu One on Android?

Comment: I'm wondering why this is distributed on Google's store instead of Fdroid repository, especially considering this is a Linux-related app. They don't link to anything but Google: https://one.ubuntu.com/downloads/android/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In general, **the latest** (or reasonably recent) APKs may be directly downloaded from Launchpad at:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntuone-android-files/

---

Here's the official APK straight from Launchpad, v. 1.1.4 released May 15, 2012:

https://launchpad.net/ubuntuone-android-files/trunk/1.1.4/+download/u1f-1.1.4-google.apk

Comment: Perfect! Thanks - should have looked on Launchpad first!

Comment: Ubuntu one music is there too.